# sorting issue biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I am using `biblatex` and  I add the resources file

```
\addbibresource{some_refs.bib}
```

I have an issue when two authors published together in the XXth and in the XXIth : in the references, $XY14$ is sorted before $XY90$

```
@book{XY90,
    author={X_name and Y_name},
    title={Some title 1},
    year={1990}
    }
        
@article{XY14,
    author={X_name and Y_name},
    title={Some title 2},
    year={2014}
    }
```

how can I fix this ?

Here is an MWE

Among my references, I have

```
@book{KS90,
        author={Kashiwara, Masaki and Schapira, Pierre},
        title={Sheaves on manifolds},
        year={1990},
        series={Grundlehren der Mathematischen Wissenschaften},
        volume={292},
        publisher={Springer-Verlag, Berlin},
        pages={x+512}
    }
    
    @book{KS96,
        author={Kashiwara, Masaki and Schapira, Pierre},
        title={Moderate and formal cohomology associated with constructible sheaves},
        year={1996},
        publisher={Citeseer}
    }

    @article{KS97,
        author={Kashiwara, Masaki and Schapira, Pierre},
        title={Integral transforms with exponential kernels and Laplace transform},
        year={1997},
        journal={Journal of the American Mathematical Society},
        volume={10},
        number={4},
        pages={939--972}
    }

    @article{KS14,
        author={Kashiwara, Masaki and Schapira, Pierre},
        title={Microlocal Euler classes and Hochschild homology},
        year={2014},
        journal={J. Inst. Math. Jussieu},
        volume={13},
        publisher={Cambridge University Press},
        pages={487--516}
    }
```

my latex file

```
\documentclass[12pt,leqno]{book}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{some_file.bib}


\begin{document}
    
\cite{KS14}

\cite{KS96}

\cite{KS90}

\cite{KS97}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={References}]

\end{document}
```

And I get as an output `KS14` showing up before `KS90`, `KS96`, `KS97`

Comment: I have the strange deja-vu that you asked that exact question just one or two days ago (though I cannot find it anymore) and that someone (Ulrike Fischer, if memory serves) already told you: Yes, it is possible, but we need a working example of your code together with the citation style you are using. Also, I am unsure whether you mean sorting of references within citations or within the bibliography.

Comment: I get correct sorting in the bibliography, using the default numeric style. The 1990 reference comes first. To fix the error, we will need to see the code that causes the error. A small example test file will be enough.

Comment: Just as I commented under you now-deleted question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/551977/35864: We really need to see a short example document that shows your bibliography setup. The answer will depend on that. (I left a longer comment under the original answer with links, you can still see your deleted question, so you can have a look at the comment if you need help with building an example document.)

Comment: @ManuelWeinkauf sorry I thought I had ill-formulated the problem so I got from a new question. So, now I provide an MWE, and I still get the same issue

Comment: @moewe sorry, I had to reformulate the question that I thought misleading in its first shape. I have just updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `style=alphabetic,` sorts bibliography entries with `sorting=anyt,` which sorts primarily by the generated label. Since "KS14" comes before "KS90" if you sort it alphanumerically you get the output you see.

One way to get the desired sorting would be to force `sorting=nyt`. Then your entries get sorted by name and (complete) year.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=alphabetic,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{KS90,
  author    = {Kashiwara, Masaki and Schapira, Pierre},
  title     = {Sheaves on manifolds},
  year      = {1990},
  series    = {Grundlehren der Mathematischen Wissenschaften},
  volume    = {292},
  publisher = {Springer-Verlag, Berlin},
  pages     = {x+512}
}
@book{KS96,
  author    = {Kashiwara, Masaki and Schapira, Pierre},
  title     = {Moderate and formal cohomology associated with constructible sheaves},
  year      = {1996},
  publisher = {Citeseer}
}
@article{KS97,
  author  = {Kashiwara, Masaki and Schapira, Pierre},
  title   = {Integral transforms with exponential kernels
             and {Laplace} transform},
  year    = {1997},
  journal = {Journal of the American Mathematical Society},
  volume  = {10},
  number  = {4},
  pages   = {939--972}
}
@article{KS14,
  author    = {Kashiwara, Masaki and Schapira, Pierre},
  title     = {Microlocal {Euler} classes and {Hochschild} homology},
  year      = {2014},
  journal   = {J. Inst. Math. Jussieu},
  volume    = {13},
  publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
  pages     = {487--516}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\autocite{KS14,KS96,KS90,KS97}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={References}]
\end{document}
```

[image: KS90, KS96, KS97, KS14]

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly